# Is there a grapichal tool for mvn release for IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am developing Java in IntelliJ and we use Maven to release our project into sub version. We have to write

```
mvn release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=X.Y.Z
mvn release:perform
mvn clean release:clean
```

in a terminal to release the project.

Is there not a better way to do this? Is there a tool in IntelliJ to do this?

I use Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA has a built in maven plugin with graphical interface:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html#d369633e1000